# bounds with trig subsitution

Tags: calculus

I have a definite integral that I know how to solve but do not know how to change the upper bound.
$\int_{0}^a\frac{1}{(a^2 +x^2)^2}dx $. with the substitution $ x = \tan\theta$,
the integral simplifies to $\frac{1}{a^4}\int\cos^4\theta d\theta $.
But the bounds give me problems. The lower bound becomes $\theta = \pi/2$
But how to deal with the upper bound $a$? $\theta = \arctan a$ ?
It does not help me much.
 The integral gets to $ \frac{1}{a^4}(\frac38\theta + \frac14 \sin 2\theta + \frac{1}{32} \sin 4\theta)/_{\pi/2}^{\arctan a }$
Then how I to simplify?

I do not see in the book's answer the $\arctan a$
The books' answer to this problem is:
$\frac{1}{8a^3}(\pi + 2)$
As I see from the kimi Tanaka's answer my main mistake was using
the wrong substitution. I should have used $ x = $a$ tan\theta$ instead of
$x = tan\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have written it with $dx$. $\int_{0}^a\frac{1}{(a^2 +x^2)^2}dx$. Let me  subsitute $ x = a\tan\theta$ and differentiate it you get $\frac{dx}{d\theta}$ = $a(1 + tan^2(\theta))$. And interval is from $x = 0$ to $x =  a$. So it is from a$tan\theta$ = 0 to a$tan\theta$ = $a$. Therefore the interval is from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$. So, original function becomes $\int_{0}^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{a(1 +tan^2(\theta))}{(a^2 +(atan\theta)^2)^2}d\theta$. I got the same answer.

Comment: I will update to show the $dx$ and $d\theta$

Answer (score 1):

The integral is from $x=0$ to $x=a$, i.e. $\tan\theta=0$ to $\tan\theta=a$ or $\theta=0$ to $\theta=\arctan a$.

As a final check, you must ensure that this defines a single interval. By monotonicity of the arc tangent, this holds.